# Scrollview in half screen rest Buttons in TableLayout?

Tags: android

Scrollview in half screen rest Buttons in TableLayout??

This is my Xml Code..It gives force close when i added the scrollView otherwise it was working fine..
What is the Problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"><View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View><ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"><TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp" android:background="@drawable/table_one">
        <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">
            <View android:layout_height="20dp"></View>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">
            <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:text="IP" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_width="70dp" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/remote_ip" android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="80"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></EditText>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">


        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_two" android:layout_height="90dp">
        <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">
            <View android:layout_height="20dp"></View>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">
            <TextView android:gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Layout Orientantion"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="40" />

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_layout" android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_weight="60"></Spinner>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_two" android:layout_height="120dp">
        <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">
            <View android:layout_height="20dp"></View>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">
            <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:text="User Name" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_width="70dp" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/remote_ip" android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="80"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">
            <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:text="Password" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_width="70dp" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/remote_ip" android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="80"
                android:password="true" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
<TableLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/my_bsckround" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:text="Save" android:id="@+id/btn_save_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"></Button>

        <Button android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/btn_setng_cncl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
```

Comment: please post your logcat to find why its happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because of the ScrollView can have only one direct child. So put your all table layouts into one linear layout like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp" android:background="@drawable/table_one">
                <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">
                    <View android:layout_height="20dp"></View>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">
                    <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:text="IP" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_width="70dp" />
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/remote_ip"
                        android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="80" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></EditText>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_two" android:layout_height="90dp">
                <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">
                    <View android:layout_height="20dp"></View>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">
                    <TextView android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Layout Orientantion"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_weight="40" />
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_layout" android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_weight="60"></Spinner>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_two" android:layout_height="120dp">
                <TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">
                    <View android:layout_height="20dp"></View>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">
                    <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:text="User Name" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_width="70dp" />
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/remote_ip"
                        android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="80" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></EditText>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp">
                    <TextView android:gravity="center|left" android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:text="Password" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_width="70dp" />
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/remote_ip"
                        android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="80" android:password="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></EditText>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
    <TableLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/my_bsckround" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:text="Save" android:id="@+id/btn_save_settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/btn_setng_cncl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp"></View>
</LinearLayout>
```